# Exponents and O notation

Tags: notation, asymptotics

Prove that if $a$ or $b$ are positive real numbers and $a<b$, then $n^a \in O(n^b)$, but $n^b \notin O(n^a)$.

Could I just take $a=1$ and $b=2$ (as an example) and prove it from there? Or do I need to provide a formal proof?

Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: Well... no, of course not. If $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers, then you can't just assume that $a = 1$ and $b = 2$.

Comment: how would u suggest to go about this then?

Comment: Your only option is to turn to the definition of Big O and show that $a < b \implies n^a \in O(n^b)$ and $a < b \implies n^b \notin O(n^a)$.

Comment: @AntonioVargas: "Your only option": don't be so pessimistic.

Comment: @YvesDaoust how would you prove the last two statements in your answer if not through the definition?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm interested to know what you mean  by that. Could you complete your answer, then?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "step". @YvesDaoust

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, provided your proof generalizes to arbitrary exponents.

---

Note that you can expresss the problem in a simpler way by the change of variable $m=n^a$, and using $r:=b/a$. The statement becomes

$$m\in O(m^r),r>1.$$

Similarly, you can rewrite the second part as

$$m\notin O(m^r),r<1.$$

These are equivalent to

$$1\in O(m^\epsilon),\\1\notin O(m^{-\epsilon})$$ for $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: how would i generalize this in terms of the definition of O notation?

Comment: @nicoba: You have to provide the proof for $1,2$ first.

Answer (score 0):

From $a \lt b$ it follows that $\lim_{n\to\infty} |\frac{n^a}{n^b}| = 0 \lt \infty$, so $n^a \in o(n^b) \in O(n^b)$.